WordPress keeps showing 403 error on console when updating post or adding new application password
My WordPress keeps showing 403 error when trying to do something like adding new post in the console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2 
       GET https://my.website.shop/mag/wp-json/wp/v2/templates/lookup?slug=single-post&_locale=user 403 (Forbidden)
       GET https://my.website.shop/mag/wp-json/wp/v2/block-patterns/categories?_locale=user 403 (Forbidden)
       OPTIONS https://my.website.shop/mag/wp-json/wp/v2/settings?_locale=user 403 (Forbidden)

I renamed the plugins directory, and even tried to add a new application password, but keeps showing 403 error:
POST https://my.website.shop/mag/wp-json/wp/v2/users/5/application-passwords?_locale=user 403 (Forbidden)

I read https://wordpress.org/support/topic/api-endpoints-return-401-errors/ and https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/ but I still have issue.
How can I fix it?

I'm not sure it's a good idea to double post your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78852260/wordpress-keeps-showing-403-error-on-console-when-updating-post-or-adding-new-ap

@mmm you're right. I forgot wordpress stachexchange. I removed the duplicate question. Regarding your other question: I have this error in admin aread.

HTTP 403 is a forbidden status code, this looks like failed authentication, though WordPress doesn't use application passwords itself, those are for external 3rd party clients, e.g. if you had a CLI application, a desktop/mobile app, or another web server making requests

@TomJNowell I know this status code. But I just see this in the console, and when I want to do things like add new post. I can login with no problem. I don't have any clues how to fix this.

do you have plugins installed that mess with authentication or add new kinds of authentication? E.g. security plugins, JWT auth, etc Have you confirmed this happens with no plugins installed and used a process of elimination?

@TomJNowell I renamed plugins directory, but nothing changed.
